# Como eu poderia ler um valor de 3 dígitos e imprimi-los na tela de forma invertida em C?

Tags: c, inteiros

Se eu armazenasse o valor '123' em uma variável do tipo inteiro, como poderia imprimir o conteúdo da variável na tela de forma invertida?

Por exemplo, para o valor '123' a saída esperada seria '321'; para '472' seria '274'.

Comment: Eu tentei deixar a perguntar mais organizada, de modo que outros que passem pelo mesmo problema consigam alcançar as respostas. Caso discorde de minha edição, é só desfazê-la ou editar as partes de discordância

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode utilizar uma solução baseada em inteiros, aplicando divisão e resto da divisão:

```
int x = 123;

while (x > 0){ //enquanto tem digitos
    printf("%d", x % 10); //mostra o ultimo digito com resto da divisão por 10
    x = x /10; //corta o ultimo digito
}
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/zi88x6)

Answer (score 1):

Use a função sprintf:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int someInt = 368;
    char str[3];
    sprintf(str, "%d", someInt);
    printf("%c%c%c", str[2], str[1], str[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seu código vai dar erro ocasional, `str` está usando 4 caracteres nas minhas contas (3 dígitos + terminados nulo)

Answer (score 1):

Para inverter o número inteiro, basta utilizar o resto e divisão do inteiro, deste modo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int numero, numIvertido;

    printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);

    if(numero >= 0){
        do{
            numIvertido = numero % 10;
            printf("%d", numIvertido);
            numero /= 10;
        }while(numero != 0);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Digite um numero inteiro: 1234567
7654321
```